# why zip object vanished?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please see the code,why list(w) properly display  ,and `h` display nothing ?

```
>>> x=[1,2,3]
>>> y=[4,5,6]
>>> w=zip(x,y)
>>> list(w)
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
>>> h=list(w)
>>> h
[]
```

Comment: works for me as expected, no problem:  `In [53]: h
Out[53]: [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]`. Can you check again and if problem persist give us interpreter version you are using?

Comment: @m.wasowski: the OP is using Python 3.  You're using 2.

Comment: yes i am in python3.3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*In Python 3*, [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) returns an [iterator](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types)<sup>1</sup>.

> Make an *iterator* that aggregates elements from each of the iterables.

An iterator remembers to where it has been iterated; at the `h=list(w)` line, the iterator is already "at the end" and thus results in an empty list/sequence.

Try with `w = list(zip(x,y))`, which would force the iterator to a list *once*.

---

<sup>1</sup> The zip from Python 2 returns a list, and thus this behavior is only exhibited in Python 3.

Comment: @New_User123 You're welcome! Sometimes the little things can be the most surprising/frustrating!